# Circle slider for weather application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have tried to look for a circle slider for an animation. It would work like the following:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
```

```js
function showValue(newValue)
{
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
```

but instead of sliding horizontally it would need to go in a circle. Is there anything similar which has been built already? I am probably not experienced enough to build it from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean by "work like the following...but instead of sliding horizontally..."? The code you've shown doesn't animate at all.

Comment: you would slide the icon but instead of going horizontally (as shown in the example) it would have to be in a circle.... This is the closest I have found...

Comment: _"instead of going horizontally (as shown in the example)"_ - But your example _doesn't slide_ or animate in any way. All it does is directly set the html content of the "range" element. Also, the element is already visible on the page, so when you say "in a circle" do you mean that it should move from where it already is in a circle around the page and finish where it started?

Comment: ok imagine the slider that instead of sliding horizontally it would in a circle as the shape is a circle and not a line (represented by the input in this case)

Comment: You would not be able to use a range input like this, it would have to be built through javascript, and would be fairly complex, unfortunately

Comment: Hi Blake, thanks for the tip but would you know any articles/tutorials where I could make a start please?

Comment: If you wanted to go about building this in javascript, you would need to track mouse position, and then calculate the angle of the mouse relative to the center of the slider using simple trigonometry (SOHCAHTOA!), and then move the slider element based on the angle,and radius of the circle. I'm sorry, I don't know any articles off hand, but if you look up the individual elements that I just described it shouldn't be too hard to find something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code you are looking for is here:

http://baijs.nl/tinycircleslider/